# Consulta inversa en Eloquent no funciona

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando usar el metodo "belongsTo" de Eloquent (Laravel) y por algun motivo no me funciona, osea no sale ningun error ni nada, solo la pagina en blanco.

Las consultas normales de uno a uno funciona bien, pero cuando intento aplicar la busqueda inversa no funciona.

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Articulo extends Model
 {
    public function Cliente(){

    //// return $this->belongsTo('App/Cliente');

    return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class);
    }
 }
```

Este es el Modelo de Articulo, intento hacer una busqueda inversa con el Cliente. La base de datos esta bien, puesto que para una busqueda normal si funciona, el problema es en la busqueda inversa, intente buscar una respuesta en la documentacion pero simplemente no funciona.

Estoy haciendo el llamado desde el archivo *web.php.*

```
Route::get("/Articulo/{id}/Cliente", function ($id) {

return \App\Articulo::find($id)->Cliente;
```

});

Comment: ¿Cuál es el nombre de tu llave foránea?, ¿puedes mostrar los nombres de las columnas de tus tablas?, por otro lado ¿seguro que ese producto si esta asociado a algún cliente?

Comment: Primero, para usar `belongsTo(Cliente::class)` debes usar su **namespace**, añade esto arriba `use App\Cliente`. Segundo, no estas usando los nombres convencionales de *Laravel* por lo cual de seguro debes especificar el nombre de tu tabla en el modelo `Cliente` o `Articulo` así: `protected $table = 'mi_tabla';`, y también como dice @BetaM la llave foránea

Comment: @Josbert no es necesario invocar al modelo por su namespace para usarlo en la declaración de la relación, eso queda resuelto al usar la sintaxis de `Modelo::class`, te recomiendo leas aqui: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: @BetaM interesante no lo sabia, estuve invocando **namespaces** por gusto todo este tiempo jaja. Muchas gracias por el dato amigo

Comment: Las tablas se llaman Clientes y Articulos 

Teniendo 
Clientes->ID y 
Articulos->ID (FK=Cliente_ID)

Ahora, con el mismo codigo cambiando solo el codigo del _find_ por un 3 (codigo que no existe) 
`return App\Articulo::find(3)->Cliente;`

me sale el error 

"Trying to get property 'Cliente' of non-object"

Comment: Me surgen las mismas dudas que plantea el primer comentario de BetaM. Por favor edita tu pregunta agregando en ella la información que te solicita para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Especifica el nombre de la llave foránea como segundo parámetro así `->belongsTo(Cliente::class, 'Cliente_ID');` te recomiendo que te sumerjas un poco en la documentación de **Laravel**, por ahora échale un ojo a [esto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: Estuve leyendo la documentacion, pero como nombraba la Llave Foranea como lo pedia Laravel, crei que no era necesario.

Answer (score 2):

Ya di con la respuesta. No entiendo porque, pero por alguna razon, aunque estoy siguiendo la convencionalidad de Laravel de llamar a la llave foranea como "NombreTabla_*ID*" no estaba asociando la llave Foranea como dijo @BetaM.

```
return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class, 'Cliente_ID', 'ID');
```

Tuve que declararlo para que si pueda asociarlos.
Muchas gracias.